# Trying to send mail to multiple recipient and cc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i am trying to send mail to multiple recipient but it sent only to single reipient and cc.
`email_dt` contain both recipient and cc email address from database.

```
string u1 = string.Empty; // cc address
string e_id = string.Empty; // recipient address
if (email_dt.Rows.Count > 0){
   for (int mail_k = 0; mail_k <= email_dt.Rows.Count - 1; mail_k++){
        if ((Convert.ToString(email_dt.Rows[mail_k][0]) != "")){
            if (Convert.ToString(email_dt.Rows[mail_k]["DESG"])=="DD"){
                e_id = Convert.ToString(email_dt.Rows[mail_k]["USR_EMAIL_ID"]);
            }
            if (Convert.ToString(email_dt.Rows[mail_k]["USR_DESG"]) == "PP"){
                u1 = Convert.ToString(email_dt.Rows[mail_k]["USR_EMAIL_ID"]);
            }
         }
    }
    message.To.Clear();
    message.To.Add(e_id);
    message.CC.Add(u1);
    smtpClient.Send(message);
}
```

I want to  send email to multiple recipient and cc. Any idea how to achieve will be appreciated

Comment: What does this have to do with Java programming? PHP?

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter just too reach wider area for solution since it's is related to concept thats why i tagged.

Comment: Yes, that will increase the visibility of your question, but doing this, also known as "language tag spamming", can also increase the risk of your question's being down-voted and close-voted because that extra attention is not always good attention. Java experts, for example, might get annoyed coming to a Java-tagged question and expecting to see Java code and direct relevance. Same for PHP. Please strive to keep your tags more specific -- for you and your question's own benefit.

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter ok

Comment: Quite simply: Your code to SEND the email is outside the loop that loops over your addresses! So you get only one email sent

Comment: Also is would appear you can set either `e_id` OR `u1` but you use BOTH these variables later and dont clear them

Answer (score 2):

Add the recipient and cc inside for loop. Try the below code.

```
string u1 = string.Empty; // cc address
string e_id = string.Empty; // recipient address
if (email_dt.Rows.Count > 0) {
   message.To.Clear();
   for (int mail_k = 0; mail_k <= email_dt.Rows.Count - 1; mail_k++) {
      if ((Convert.ToString(email_dt.Rows[mail_k][0]) != "")) {
          if (Convert.ToString(email_dt.Rows[mail_k]["DESG"])=="DD") {
             e_id = Convert.ToString(email_dt.Rows[mail_k]["USR_EMAIL_ID"]);
           }
           if (Convert.ToString(email_dt.Rows[mail_k]["USR_DESG"]) == "PP") {
             u1 = Convert.ToString(email_dt.Rows[mail_k]["USR_EMAIL_ID"]);
           }
           if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e_id))
             message.To.Add(e_id);
           if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(u1))
             message.CC.Add(u1); 
        }
    }
    smtpClient.Send(message);
}
```

Comment: i have tried the same way but getting error The parameter 'addresses' cannot be an empty string.\r\nParameter name: addresses

Comment: This exception is being thrown by the MailAddress constructor. It means you are trying to add an empty string as an email address, which is not valid email. Just make a check before adding the email id in message.To and message.CC. I have updated the answer.